# Getting a variable from javascript to a property of a webcontrol

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I am wondering if i can get the session value and put as a parameter to a control i have.

This is the code I currently have:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var workspacepath = '<%= Session["workspacepath"].ToString() %>';
        var workspacename = '<%= Session["workspacename"].ToString() %>';
    </script>

    <iz:FileManager ID="FileManager1" runat="server" Height="550" Width="1016px" FileViewMode="Details"
        ClientOpenItemFunction="funcinvisiblebutton1">
        <RootDirectories>
            <iz:RootDirectory DirectoryPath="~/" Text="Workspace Etteplan" />
        </RootDirectories>
    </iz:FileManager>
    </div>
```

I want the session value in DirectoryPath="~/".

Comment: It's not possible to do in the Markup with Server Controls. Is there a reason you can't access this in the `Page_Load` or `Page_Init` events in the Code Behind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set attribute value :

```
document.getElementsByTagName("iz:RootDirectory")[0].setAttribute("DirectoryPath",workspacepath);
```